# Vista C Compiler

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, compile

What is a good C compiler for Windows Vista?

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120533/c-c-compiler-for-vista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mingw works. ( http://www.mingw.org/ ) Mingw is a port of GNUCC to Windows.

You can also use Code::Blocks IDE which comes with MinGW.

TinyC Compiler is another compiler, but i prefer MinGW myself. :)

Answer (score 17):

Visual C++ 2008. The [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) is even free.

Preemptive answers: yes, it can compile C code as well as C++ code, and it can compile native code as well as managed .NET code.

---

Update: see [matthew's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/24339/vista-c-compiler/24368#24368) for instructions on how to configure VC++ to compile pure C code.

Comment: I have tried it before and it was a painto figure out how it worked

Comment: If you add a link to how to get VC++ to compile specifically to pure C code, I'll delete my answer (wish I had more karma to do it myself).

Answer (score 6):

[Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) with it set to compile to [pure, unadulterated C.](http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/qt/compilingc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[code blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org)

or

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/)

or

[netbeans + add-on for C/C++ Complier](http://www.netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/c++/)

Comment: Your two first links is the same url.

Comment: any reason for down vote?

Answer (score 0):

dev C++ is a good and lightweight compiler for any version of windows. http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html

Comment: Definitely +1 for Dev-C++.  Its a bit outdated (no native 64bit version yet).  I cut my teeth on bloodshed's software (and remember my mom freaking when she found "bloodshed.net" in the history when I was in high school) and later moved on to Visual Studio before settling on the Linux CLI (vim/emacs + gcc).

Comment: -1 for Dev-C++. It's adondandware. Go with something that's actually maintained / updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to dive into the command line (and as a programmer, you should expect to eventually), the Gnu Compiler Collection is a great choice.  Its been around since pretty much forever (1980s in real-life terms) and it or its offshoots can compile most anything (Ada, anyone?) and target most anything (TIGCC if you want to write for your TI graphing calculator).

If the command line is still too scary, there are a few front ends to make things easier.

GCC, however, isn't a full on development environment.  You'll have to use a separate text editor, of which there are many good ones on Vista (I'm partial to Vim for Windows, Emacs, and Notepad++, all of which support syntax highlighting and auto-indentation).

Answer (score 0):

The free command line Borland C++ 5.5 is good.